# Using mysql database to authenticate users in Spring security?

Tags: mysql, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-jdbc

I want to use Spring security to authenticate users in my web application..
Since am  not a matured user to Spring framework ,i can't get a clear idea about how we can do the configuration settings to use jdbc-user-service ..
i had done the following configurations.but its not working

```xml
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
         <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>        
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="admin"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="admin"/>
</beans:bean>
```

..can anyone please help me to solve the issue with a sample config file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your problem? Can you post stack traces, or a clearer descriptions of any issues you're facing?

Answer (score 6):

You usually do it with a custom [`UserDetailsService`](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html). The `UserDetailsService` is a DAO used to load data about a user when they attempt login. Have a look at the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method and the `UserDetails` class in spring.

Yo need to define it in your context:

```xml
<bean id="myDetailsService"
    class="com.company.service.impl.MyDetailsService" />
```

To use it you can add this to your security config:

```xml
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

and all you security filters will use it.

You can ask a more specific question if you need help implementing it, but you won't have trouble IMO.

Comment: can u just give a brief about its implementation too..i have tried for that but its not getting.

Comment: you can see details about the implementation in the link provided in the answer. http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html

Comment: Link is broken. Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171460/using-mysql-database-to-authenticate-users-in-spring-security.

Answer (score 6):

another way to do this is to create tables using the standard spring security database schema (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html). Then you can simply use spring's jdbc-userservice:

```xml
<security:authentication-provider >
    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" /> 
    <security:password-encoder hash="sha" />
</security:authentication-provider>
```

Or if you want to use your own schema you can override the queries like this:

```xml
<security:authentication-provider>
    <securiy:jdbc-user-service 
      data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query="select username, password from users where username=?"
      authorities-by-username-query="select username, roleName from role..."
      role-prefix="ROLE_"
    />
 </security:authentication-provider>
```

Comment: is this query fixed? Because when i change the query according to my tables this does not work, it works only when i design according to this query.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your `<authentication-provider>` tag:

```xml
<authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
                SELECT username, password, enabled
                FROM user WHERE username = ?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
                SELECT u.username, r.role_name
                FROM user u, user_role r, assigned_role a
                WHERE u.id = a.username
                AND r.id = a.role_id
                AND u.username = ?"
        />
</authentication-provider>
```

Of course you'll have to tweak the queries to match your table names.