# spring mvc hibernate to form log in page, authorities and authentication questions

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm really new with Spring mvc, security and hibernate. So I just a have a few questions.

I'm using a mysql database and would like to create a log-in page. While reading stuff online, it says that I would need some authorities fields. Is that required?

For now, I have the following:

```
HibernateUtil.java
UserInfoHelper.java - this implements query methods
Userinfo.hbm.xml
Userinfo.java - contains all the fields from my userinfo table
UserinfoId.java = contains id related fields from my userinfo table
```

.

Basically, the files above except the UserInfoHelper was generated by a hibernate tool on netbeans.

For my applicationContext.xml I got:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

          <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

How do I start creating spring security, mvc with database authentication?

Thank you!

Comment: Please perform search before posting question. possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171460/using-mysql-database-to-authentaicate-users-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

[example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) for spring security with JDBC.

Comment: Thank you! Is it necessary for me to have the user_roles table? Or what if I dont want to use that feature?